# React: Create a new element from all children while adding props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, children

I'm trying to loop over all children and add a prop to it. The problem is it works for all immediate children, but the "grandchildren" if you will, do not also receive the new props. Here is the code snippet:

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
  React.createElement(
     child.type, 
     Object.assign({}, {...child.props}, {newProp: "test"}),
  )
)
```

All of the immediate children retain their props, as well as gain `prop.newProp` and the grandchildren are also returned, but without `newProp`. Passing the children in like so also does not work:

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
  React.createElement(
     child.type, 
     Object.assign({}, {...child.props}, {newProp: "test"}),
     child.props.children
  )
)
```

**Edit:**

- Plain old ReactJS answers please, without the use of additional libraries such as Redux.

Comment: Why is the parent to propagate the props to grand children and not the children themselves?

Comment: It is meant to propagate props to the children as well. And the grandchildren.

Comment: And the grand grand children? I think when you try to do something like that you should look at "context" it's same as props but will be automatically propagate to all children, and all grand children... take a look at the doc, it's a nice feature https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: Oh wow, how did I miss context in the api. Very interesting. If you don't mind please add this as an answer, and I'll up vote and then select if someone else doesn't have a way to do this without the experimental api.

Answer (score 1):

So I put it as an answer. You can use the [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) feature to expose some props to all the children without passing them into children, grandchildren, etc...

According to the documentation this is an experimental feature, but many libraries like Redux use it.

Just be sure what you are passing among the context, IMO you must think twice before using it

Answer (score 0):

[Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) allows container components to manage and map its state to react presentational components' props.

Comment: Not using Redux. This is to couple a self-contained component library without Redux / Flux or other stores.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to add props to all children in a React component:

```
<div>
  { React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { hello: 'world' }) }
</div>
```

Comment: This adds to all levels of children? Children of children, etc?